# From where Ubuntu help(yelp) reads its files?

Tags: documentation, yelp

I tried to remove Ubuntu Desktop Guide from Yelp(Ubuntu help)..

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-docs
```

But still shown whenever I open help?!

From where are those files? and how yelp treat them? and how to get rid totally of those ubuntu-docs?!

In fact yelp is responsible for showing two documentation one for for gnome-help which can be founded under path: `/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help` and other for Ubuntu,unity which can you show files under `/usr/share/help/C/ubuntu-help`, but when you purge `ubuntu-docs` this folder is removed but still documentation still available in Yelp!!!

I'm getting confused from where yelp is providing this documentation?!!!

Comment: The docs come in about 60 languages. Do you still have some of the other languages installed? (which can include versions of English other than U.S.. "C"). Look for other `ubuntu-help` directories under `/usr/share/help`, such as en_CA or en_GB or en_AU.

Comment: Oh, and it might be using a language pack specific version under `/usr/share/help-langpack`. On my system to find everywhere ubuntu-docs stuff was stored, I picked a file name at random and did `locate a11y-braille.page`

Comment: @DougSmythies you can delete those language packs and nothing happens, try it :)

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be some weirdness going on. I am in Canada, and so yelp is using the en_CA stuff on my system. However, yelp doesn't pick up any changes unless I modify the the "C" version of the file, but then it picks up the new en_CA version. Yelp must cache stuff somewhere, but I haven't been able to figure out where. I am on the ubuntu-docs team and will try to get help from some others.

Comment: @DougSmythies thanks friend...that exactly what make me confused with..   It's not affected by neither langpack nor ubuntu-docs

Answer (score 1):

The translated pages (everything but en_US) belong to the **language-pack-gnome-[LANG]-base** packages. When both those and the **ubuntu-docs** package have been removed, you shouldn't be able to view the docs.

*Edit:*

```
$ echo $LANGUAGE
sv
$ sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-docs language-pack-gnome-sv-base
Läser paketlistor... Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd         
Läser tillståndsinformation... Färdig
Följande paket kommer att TAS BORT:
  language-pack-gnome-sv* language-pack-gnome-sv-base* ubuntu-docs*
0 att uppgradera, 0 att nyinstallera, 3 att ta bort och 0 att inte uppgradera.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer 63,9 MB att frigöras på disken.
Vill du fortsätta? [J/n] j
(Läser databasen ... 636783 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Tar bort ubuntu-docs (15.04.3) ...
Tar bort language-pack-gnome-sv-base (1:15.04+20150615) ...
Raderar konfigurationsfiler för language-pack-gnome-sv-base (1:15.04+20150615) ...
Tar bort language-pack-gnome-sv (1:15.04+20150615) ...
Hanterar utlösare för software-center (13.10-0ubuntu6.1) ...
INFO:softwarecenter.db.update:translation information in database is up-to-date
Hanterar utlösare för bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
$
```

Then, when calling yelp, I get a "Document Not Found" message.

Comment: I don't think so, you can test it your self make some edit in those lang packs, though you'll not see your changes in yelp. Moreover I did already remove ubuntu-docs and language-pack-gnome-[LANG]-base and still having the documentation valid :)

Comment: @Maythux: I just edited my answer. Probably there is some misconception involved here.

Comment: I did the procedure as per Gunnar's instructions. In my case Language was "en_CA:en". It worked for me. Now, I will re-install.